# group json data by columns

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

i have json array

```
let arr = [
  { EMAIL: 'john@example.com', LASTNAME: 'Smith', FIRSTNAME: 'John', SMS: '33123456789' },
  { EMAIL: 'harry@example.com', LASTNAME: 'Pierce', FIRSTNAME: 'Harry', SMS: '33111222222' },
  { EMAIL: 'howard@example.com', LASTNAME: 'Paige', FIRSTNAME: 'Howard', SMS: '33777888898' },
];
```

i want output like

```
EMAIL : {"john@example.com","harry@example.com","howard@example.com"}
LASTNAME={"Smith", "Pierce","Paige"}
```

i tried many things , i came up with one solution with hardcore column name

```
var arr3=["EMAIL", "LASTNAME", "FIRSTNAME", "SMS"];

let arr_email=[];

arr.forEach(function(e, i) {

    arr_email.push(arr[i]['EMAIL']) 
})

var arr2=[];

arr2.push({"EMAIL":arr_email});
```

But I am looking for generic solution . I dont want to pass hardcore column name.
please suggest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated: Fixed naming and initialisation to make everything consistent.

Use something like this:

```
let arr=[{EMAIL: "john@example.com", LASTNAME: "Smith", FIRSTNAME: "John", SMS: "33123456789"}
    ,{EMAIL: "harry@example.com", LASTNAME: "Pierce", FIRSTNAME: "Harry", SMS: "33111222222"}
    ,{EMAIL: "howard@example.com", LASTNAME: "Paige", FIRSTNAME: "Howard", SMS: "33777888898"}]
let newObject = {}

arr.forEach(element => {
  Object.keys(element).forEach(key => { 
  if(!newObject[key]) {
    newObject[key] = []
  }
  newObject[key].push(element[key]) 
  })
})
```

So you'll have in:

```
console.log(newObject)
```

Something like:

```
EMAIL: (3) ["john@example.com", "harry@example.com", "howard@example.com"]
FIRSTNAME: (3) ["John", "Harry", "Howard"]
LASTNAME: (3) ["Smith", "Pierce", "Paige"]
SMS: (3) ["33123456789", "33111222222", "33777888898"]
```

Comment: one more question , i want to extract column name also like email .. what can i try ?

Comment: Would break if not all items in array have [exactly the same properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58707307/1641941).

Comment: @NeerajVerma column name it's a String Key of your object. Sorry, I did a mistake with naming, newArr is not an array, it's an object. I've changed it.

Comment: @HMR it's not related to my response.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through keys of object and push their items according to the key. It can be done using `reduce` method and then you can use `destruct` operator. Let me show an example:

```js
const arr=[
   {EMAIL: "john@example.com", LASTNAME: "Smith", FIRSTNAME: "John", SMS: "33123456789"},
   {EMAIL: "harry@example.com", LASTNAME: "Pierce", FIRSTNAME: "Harry", SMS: "33111222222"},
   {EMAIL: "howard@example.com", LASTNAME: "Paige", FIRSTNAME: "Howard", SMS: "33777888898"}
]

const allKeysWithData = arr.reduce((a, c) => {
  for (const name in c){
      a[name] = a[name] || [];
      a[name].push(c[name]);
  }
  return a;
}, {});

const { FIRSTNAME, SMS, ...result} = allKeysWithData;
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Would break if not all items in array have [exactly the same properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58707307/1641941).

Comment: @HMR I am sorry. I cannot understand what you mean. Could you clarify, please?

Comment: I put a link there, try your code with arr of second example. (say if second item of array has missing SMS)

Comment: @HMR thanks for the clarification. I've tried to delete `SMS` property from second item and it works.

Comment: Try to remove an email from one item, you end up with email having 2 items and last name having 3 items. You now don't know what name does not have an email.

Comment: @HMR in my view, OP asked just to make the desired result without hard coding. There is no goal to recreate a connection between name and email. At least, this goal cannot be seen from the OP’s question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys` to get dynamic column like this:

```js
let arr=[{EMAIL: "john@example.com", LASTNAME: "Smith", FIRSTNAME: "John", SMS: "33123456789"}
        ,{EMAIL: "harry@example.com", LASTNAME: "Pierce", FIRSTNAME: "Harry", SMS: "33111222222"}
        ,{EMAIL: "howard@example.com", LASTNAME: "Paige", FIRSTNAME: "Howard", SMS: "33777888898"}]
const keys = Object.keys(arr[0])

const result = {};
arr.forEach(item => {
  keys.forEach(key => {
    if (!result[key]) {
      result[key] = [item[key]]
    } else {
      result[key].push(item[key])
    }
  })
})
console.log('result:', result)
```

Comment: one more question , i want to extract column name also like email .. what can i try ?

Comment: Would break if not all items in array have [exactly the same properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58707307/1641941).

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr = [
  { EMAIL: 'john@example.com', LASTNAME: 'Smith', FIRSTNAME: 'John', SMS: '33123456789' },
  { EMAIL: 'harry@example.com', LASTNAME: 'Pierce', FIRSTNAME: 'Harry', SMS: '33111222222' },
  { EMAIL: 'howard@example.com', LASTNAME: 'Paige', FIRSTNAME: 'Howard', SMS: '33777888898' },
];


var obj = {};
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(arr[i])) {
       obj[key] = (obj[key] || []);
        obj[key].push(value); 
   }
}
console.log(obj)
let {EMAIL, LASTNAME} = obj;
```

Comment: Would break if not all items in array have [exactly the same properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58707307/1641941).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) with array map and reduce:

```js
const arr = [
  {EMAIL: 'john@example.com',LASTNAME: 'Smith',FIRSTNAME: 'John',SMS: '33123456789',},
  {EMAIL: 'harry@example.com',LASTNAME: 'Pierce',FIRSTNAME: 'Harry',SMS: '33111222222',},
  {EMAIL: 'howard@example.com',LASTNAME: 'Paige',FIRSTNAME: 'Howard',SMS: '33777888898',},
];

const [EMAIL, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SMS] = arr
  .map(({ EMAIL, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SMS }) => [
    EMAIL,
    LASTNAME,
    FIRSTNAME,
    SMS,
  ])
  .reduce(
    (result, item) =>
      item.reduce((r, i, index) => {
        r[index].push(i);
        return r;
      }, result),
    [[], [], [], []]
  );
console.log(EMAIL, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, SMS);
```

That assumes you already know the properties in every item of the array, if you don't and have to do it dynamically then all the other answers would break if not every item in the array has the same amount of properties.

To group dynamically with not all items in the array having exactly the same properties you can do the following:

```js
const arr = [
  //missing sms
  {EMAIL: 'john@example.com',LASTNAME: 'Smith',FIRSTNAME: 'John'},
  //missing last name
  {EMAIL: 'harry@example.com',FIRSTNAME: 'Harry',SMS: '33111222222',},
  {EMAIL: 'howard@example.com',LASTNAME: 'Paige',FIRSTNAME: 'Howard',SMS: '33777888898',},
];
//get unique keys of all items in array
const keys = [
  ...arr
    .reduce(
      (result, item) =>
        Object.keys(item).reduce(
          (result, key) => result.add(key),
          result
        ),

      new Set()
    )
    .values(),
];
const map = arr.reduce(
  (result, item) =>
    keys.reduce(
      (result, key) =>
        result.set(
          key,
          (result.get(key) || []).concat(item[key])
        ),
      result
    ),
  new Map()
);
console.log(Object.fromEntries(map.entries()) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that `{"john@example.com","harry@example.com","howard@example.com"}` this is not a valid object in javascript.

You meant to array, you can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) & [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in order to group it.

```js
const arr = [{
    EMAIL: 'john@example.com',
    LASTNAME: 'Smith',
    FIRSTNAME: 'John',
    SMS: '33123456789'
  },
  {
    EMAIL: 'harry@example.com',
    LASTNAME: 'Pierce',
    FIRSTNAME: 'Harry',
    SMS: '33111222222'
  },
  {
    EMAIL: 'howard@example.com',
    LASTNAME: 'Paige',
    FIRSTNAME: 'Howard',
    SMS: '33777888898'
  },
];

const result = arr.reduce((res, current) => {
  Object.keys(current).forEach(key => {
    res[key] = res[key] || [];
    res[key].push(current[key]);
  })
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Would break if not all items in array have [exactly the same properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58707307/1641941).

Comment: It won't break it will contain `undefined` in "empty" places.

Comment: It may just be an edge case but say data comes from a server then `JSON.stringify({hi:undefined})` will be `{}`. Just put the comment since this question is answer bombed with answers that have a breaking edge case. OP may never experience this but other people using the answers may have this edge case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function to get the desired output

```
var keys = Object.keys(this.arr[0])

        var result = keys.map(key => {
          return { key: this.arr.map(s => s[key]) }
        })
```

Comment: Would break if not all items in array have [exactly the same properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58707307/1641941).