# React js convert grouped column array into normal Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

i have a grouped array like this

```
this.state.tableData=

[0:{key: "EMAIL",val:  ["john@example.com", "harry@example.com", "howard@example.com"]}
1:{key: "LASTNAME",val:  ["Smith", "Pierce", "Paige"]}
2:{key: "FIRSTNAME",val: ["John", "Harry", "Howard"]}
3:{key: "SMS",val: ["33123456789", "33111222222", "33777888898"]}
]
```

i want to convert it to normal array like

```
0: {EMAIL: "john@example.com", LASTNAME: "Smith", FIRSTNAME: "John", SMS: "33123456789"}
1: {EMAIL: "harry@example.com", LASTNAME: "Pierce", FIRSTNAME: "Harry", SMS: "33111222222"}
2: {EMAIL: "howard@example.com", LASTNAME: "Paige", FIRSTNAME: "Howard", SMS: "33777888898"}
```

i have tried following code

```
this.state.csvHeaders=["EMAIL','FIRSTNAME','LASTNAME']

var contacts=[];
this.state.tableData.map(k => {

        k.val.map(r => {

        Object.keys(this.state.csvHeaders).forEach(key => {

             if(k.val["Col"]==="EMAIL")
             {
                contacts[key]['EMAIL']=r;
             }

        })

        })

    })
```

but it doesnt work .... any suggestion what more can i modified .how can i store , push them to array ?

Comment: Is key and val inside a JSON object?

Comment: @Neeraj Verma your this.state.tableData is right json ? or objects of array

Comment: that's not a proper js datastructure, especially the array is not correctly syntactically: `["Smith", "Pierce", "Paige", Col: "LASTNAME"]` - the part  `Col: "LASTNAME" ` is not a proper array element. Please edit your question with the correct data structures

Comment: ok , i removed the col , now please tell me how it can be possible ?

Comment: Just to make sure, you don't actually have the index of the array items written before them in the code, do you? Because your grouped array is still not a syntactically correct array in JS.

Comment: You already [had a normal array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58707195/group-json-data-by-columns) why can't you use that one?

Answer (score 3):

Something along these lines should work:

```
    const tableData= [
        {key: "EMAIL",val:  ["john@example.com", "harry@example.com", "howard@example.com"]},
        {key: "LASTNAME",val:  ["Smith", "Pierce", "Paige"]},
        {key: "FIRSTNAME",val: ["John", "Harry", "Howard"]},
        {key: "SMS",val: ["33123456789", "33111222222", "33777888898"]},
];
const csvHeaders = ['EMAIL','FIRSTNAME','LASTNAME', 'SMS'];

const contacts = [];
csvHeaders.forEach( (header, idx) => {

        tableData[0].val.forEach( (info, contactPos) => {
                contacts[contactPos] = contacts[contactPos] || {};
                contacts[contactPos][header] =  tableData.find(row => row.key === header).val[contactPos];
        })
})

console.log(contacts);
```

Comment: 0:
EMAIL: "john@example.com"
FIRSTNAME: "john@example.com"
LASTNAME: "john@example.com"
SMS: "john@example.com"

Comment: right, I haven't looked very closely to the actual result. I updated the code with what works now :)

Comment: now it worked ...perfect solution ... thanks ... yes my syntax need correction .. i will do it

Comment: wait . one bug i found .. if  i changes key : "EMAIL" to key : "SMS" . .. then still array pushes email data in it . this should not happen

Comment: Right, I've updated the code to make it search in `tableData` by current header.

Answer (score 3):

You can use reduce and forEach to do this:

```js
var tableData = [
  { key: 'EMAIL',val: ['john@example.com','harry@example.com','howard@example.com'],},
  { key: 'LASTNAME', val: ['Smith', 'Pierce', 'Paige'] },
  { key: 'FIRSTNAME', val: ['John', 'Harry', 'Howard'] },
  { key: 'SMS',val: ['33123456789', '33111222222', '33777888898'],},
];

console.log(
  tableData.reduce((result, { key, val }) => {
    val.forEach((val, index) => {
      result[index] = result[index] || {};
      result[index][key] = val;
    });
    return result;
  }, [])
);
```

Comment: Great solution!:)